# How to find an expression and replace with the file name for a .txt in bash using xargs and sed?

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I want to find an expression in a particular file and replace it with the current name of the file used from the script. My current script is :

```
for FILE in ../pdb/*; 

    do

    basename $FILE .pdb | xargs -I '{}' sed -i  's/_final.pdb/{}_final.pdb/g' ./temp.txt

    ./program < temp.txt

    done
```

The output in psfgen.inp contain the name of every files and not only the current file :

writepdb fileAfileBfileC_final.pdb

and it should like :

writepdb fileA_final.pdb

How to replace the current basename in temp.txt to let the program use temp.txt before it write the next basename from the loop instead of writing the basename of all files in the folder before executing the program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was only to replace the whole line like this :

```
for FILE in ../pdb/*; 

    do

    basename $FILE .pdb | xargs -I '{}' sed -i  '/_final.pdb/c\writepdb {}_final.pdb' ./temp.txt

    ./program < temp.txt

    done
```